# Button with onserverclick will not response

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code in

**ASPX:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button"
                    class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
                    data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#navbar"
                    aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand"
               href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar"
             class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text"
                           placeholder="Username"
                           class="form-control"
                           runat="server" required
                           id="username" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password"
                           placeholder="Password"
                           class="form-control"
                           runat="server" required
                           id="password" />
                </div>
                <input type="submit"
                       class="btn btn-success"
                       runat="server"
                       onserverclick="login_Click"
                       value="Sign in" />
            </form>
        </div>
        <!--/.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>
```

whenever I press the button it will not go to he login_Click function in the `Code Behind`. Someone help me please thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like @Mohit said firstly give an ID to your input tag in your **YourPageName.aspx** page

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" runat="server" onserverclick="login_ServerClick" id="login" value="Sign in" />
```

and last thing you need to add an on click event in your code behind **YourPageName.aspx.cs**

```
protected void login_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //string a = "alert('your request has been submitted successfully !');";
    //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, typeof(Page), "x", a, true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two changes which could do the trick

First is give the ID to the button and Secondly add OnClick Something like this

```
<input type="submit"
       class="btn btn-success"
       runat="server"
       onserverclick="login_Click"
       value="Sign in"
       onclick="__doPostBack('login','')"
       id="login" />
```

Comment: OH that's why. thanks. I just copied that template from bootstrap and added some missing attrib thanks.

Comment: I am hoping you have protected modifer to your `login_Click` function

Comment: the login_Click function is in public :)

Comment: `<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="YourPageName.aspx.cs" Inherits="ClassNameOfCodeBehindeWithFullNamespace" %>`
above needs to be there on top of your your aspx page and You need to add protected modifier for your methods.

Comment: already have that on the top of my aspx page. I really don't understand i just added bootstrap template for my login page. actually I can login before i added some templates but now it will not go to the code behind.

Comment: I just got the answer :) I didn't add runat="server" in the form tag from the template :) what a mistake. By the way thanks for helping me. And I consider your answer :)